# GeoServer YSLD - Point Stacking with multiple features on map

Tags: boundless-suite, ysld

So, there isn't much information out there: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/ysld/reference/transforms.html#point-stacker

And I have successfully used this doc to create a simply style that stacks soil sample points on my map (Geoserver for Boundless Suite).

What I have been given now is dataset with multiple types of features where I need to use the 
filter: ${entity_feature_here = 'Example'} multiple tikes to have each of the (10+) features render on the map. When I do this, it obviously looks cluttered. What I can't figure out is how to use Point Stacker to cluster each of these points until they are zoomed in.  When I do try, all my data seems to vanish.

```
name: YSLD_Point_Staclk
feature-styles:
- name: PointStacker
  transform:
    name: vec:PointStacker
    params:
      cellSize: 64
  rules:
  - name: 'Example 1'
    filter: ${entity_feature_here = 'Example1'}
    title: Example 1
    scale: [min, max]
    symbolizers:
    - point:
        size: 10
        symbols:
        - mark:
            shape: circle
            fill-color: #some color
  - name: 'Example 2'
    filter: ${entity_feature_here = 'Example2'}
    title: Example 2
    scale: [min, max]
    symbolizers:
    - point:
        size: 10
        symbols:
        - mark:
            shape: circle
            fill-color: #some color
  - name: 'Example 3'
    filter: ${entity_feature_here = 'Example3}
    title: No Plant Area
    scale: [min, max]
    symbolizers:
    - point:
        size: 10
        symbols:
        - mark:
            shape: square
            fill-color: #some color
```

I have tried it with and with setting the [min,max] and I have tried getting rid of the scale all together as is shown in the example in the Geoserver doc. Neither has worked, my data just disappears on the map.

Comment: Probably unrelated, or just an error while you tried to clean up the code, but `filter: ${entity_feature_here = 'Example3}` isn't right.

Comment: It works though, and shows properly in the legend and the Geoserver suite application. Might that be a reason that the point stacker isn't working?

Comment: its not closed correctly so anything is possible.